# Angular2 modal box primeng customization

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm struggling with a modal box customization.
I want to take this modal box
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/dialog/dialog.ts
and add a few functionalities.
The problem I encouter is with

```
[@dialogState]="visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"
```

I get the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Can't bind to '@dialogState' since it isn't a known native property ("e ? 'block' : 'none'" [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height" (mousedown)="moveOnTop()" [ERROR ->][@dialogState]="visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
            <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget"): FullDialog@2:135
```

I thought the code would work out of the box. What I understand of this is that angular2 is looking for a class member named dialogState but it is not finding it. However I see that there is a variable named dialogState in the animations section of the class decorator. What can I do to get rid of this error? I would appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the square brackets around @dialogState as per the example in the docs.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html